# Иконки на сайте бутстрапа

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Здесь куча кнопок с иконками. Вопрос: как сделано, чтобы иконки нельзя было просмотреть через firebug? Или я не там смотрю?
Так как штука халявная, задачи стырить простыню иконок не стоит. Задача стоит понять как она реализована.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эти иконки реализованы через специальный шрифт, о чем говорит говорит прямо первое предложение на этой странице:

> Includes over 250 glyphs in font format from the Glyphicon Halflings set.

Можете почитать про это поподробнее [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/ikonki-veb-shriftov-alternativa-izobrazheniyam). [Вот](http://fontawesome.veliovgroup.com/) еще хорошая реализация.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотреть на самом деле можно, реализовано это, как уже написали до меня, через специальный шрифт. А контент, который выводится, формируется псевдоэлементом :before. В firebug, насколько я знаю, подобное посмотреть не получится, а вот инспектор элементов mozilla подобное отображать умеет. Вот, например, наугад взятый псевдоэлемент :before для иконки евро (класс glyphicon-euro)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Файрбаг тоже показывал, просто я искал img или background. А элемент, который я выбрал имел левый символ, который мозиллка не знала. Там был просто квадратик.